# How to resize List items with a sidebar style

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to reduce the size of the items in a `List` view, more precisely the *height*, the list being styled like a sidebar (`.listStyle(.sidebar)`). I tried changing the size with `.controlSize(.mini)` but it didn't work. It worked for other list styles (plain, bordered, etc.).

What strikes me is that Xcode sidebar does have list items that are smaller than the regular size, so it should be possible !

[Side by side comparison between Xcode sidebar and my app sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSdBV.png)

Is there a simple and idiomatic way to do this ?

Comment: It looks like the font of your app sidebar is larger then Xcode's, perhaps reduce the font size and see how it looks

Comment: @Chris Tried it, but no success :') Thanks for the suggestion though !

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I am not correctly understanding the question but can't you just set the `frame` of the items? For example:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach((1...10), id: \.self) {_ in
                Text("hello")
                    .frame(height: 50) // <- Right here!
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

Where 50 would be the height you want.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ! No I can't seem to decrease the list item size to how I want with your suggestion. However I noticed I can increase it, meaning there is a minimum height to my list item (If you try an height like 10 or 8 you'll see the height won't change), but I don't understand why.